# Copying data from a column in a datagrid to an array

Tags: apache-flex

I have an editable column in a datagrid. How do i copy the contents of that column into an array? The dataprovider for the datagrid is an array

Comment: what do you mean "copy the contents"? you want to generate an array that contains just the values found in that column or somehow convert the contents of a cell to an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each index on the dataProvider corresponds to a row in the datagrid, so, each column cell must be a property on the object in that index. All you need to do then is loop through your dataprovider, and in each iteration take the value from the column and push it to a separate array that will contain all the data for that column. If that's not clear I wouldn't mind whipping you up an example.

Answer (score 0):

i think your Datagrid has the Dataprovider as an ArrayCollection? Is it like this?

There are some evebts for an Datagrid, like click or edit or something else. The Eventhandler receice the object from the DG, so you have the row.
To add an Object into an Array(puch) or ArrayCollection (.addItem(At)) is easy.

Is this what you want? If not, please describe your problem deeper, when you want to do what.

BR
Frank

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, you should be able to define a handler for the click event and take the selectedItem, like:

--- mxml ---

```
<s:DataGrid
id="myGrid"
click="handle()"
dataProvider="{myAC}"/>
```

--- ascript ---

```
private function handle():void{
var myResult:Array = new Array;
myResult = myGrid.selectedItem._YOUR_SPECIFIC_COLUMN;
```

}

Regards /dley